# How to generate a signature based on an XML file?

Tags: java, cryptography, .net-3.5, signature, x++

please help me to solve the following:
I have a code on Java
java code bellow:

```
StringBuilder fullText;
KeyStore p12 = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
p12.load(new FileInputStream("FileName.p12"), "1234".toCharArray());

Key key = (Key) p12.getKey("1", "1234".toCharArray());

//signing
Signature signer = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");

signer.initSign((PrivateKey) key);
signer.update(fullText.toString().getBytes());
b`yte[] digitalSignature = signer.sign();

String base64sign = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(digitalSignature));
```

I tried to reproduce it on .Net platform.
I create a code on .NET 3.5 platform. The code on X++ below:

```
public static boolean Encrypt(str sXmlDoc)
{
    boolean bSuccess = false;

    System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 p12;
    System.Security.Cryptography.AsymmetricAlgorithm key;

    str sBase64Cert;
    str sBase64Xml;
    str sBase64Sign;

    str sTmp;

    System.Byte[] byteArray;
    System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.Signature signer;
    System.Exception  ex;
    str sKeyPublic;
    System.Byte[] keyPublic;
    System.Int32 myInt32;
    int myInt;
    System.Byte[] byteTmp, byteTmp2;
    System.Text.ASCIIEncoding txtEncoder;
    System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.KeyInfo keyInfo;
    System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml signedXml;
    System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlDocument;
    System.Xml.XmlElement xmlElement;
    System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedInfo signedInfo;
    System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.Reference reference;
    System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform env;

    System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.RSAKeyValue rsaKeyValue;
    System.Security.Cryptography.RSA rsaKey;

    try
    {


        p12 = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2("fileName.p12", "pass");
        if (p12)
        {
            //Signature

            //TEST
            if (p12.get_HasPrivateKey())
            {
                key = p12.get_PrivateKey();
                rsaKey = p12.get_PrivateKey();

                xmlDocument = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
                xmlDocument.set_PreserveWhitespace(true); //Allow white spaces
                xmlDocument.LoadXml(sXmlDoc);
                signedXml = new System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml(xmlDocument);
                signedXml.set_SigningKey(key);
                keyInfo = new System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.KeyInfo();
                rsaKeyValue = new System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.RSAKeyValue(rsaKey);
                keyInfo.AddClause(rsaKeyValue);
                signedXml.set_KeyInfo(keyInfo);
                // Create a reference to be signed.
                //System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.Reference reference;
                reference = new System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.Reference();
                reference.set_Uri("");
                // Add an enveloped transformation to the reference.
                env = new System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform();
                reference.AddTransform(env);
                // Add the reference to the SignedXml object.
                signedXml.AddReference(reference);
                signedXml.set_KeyInfo(keyInfo);
                signedXml.ComputeSignature();
                xmlElement = signedXml.GetXml();
                signer = new System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.Signature();
                signer = signedXml.get_Signature();
                signedInfo = new System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedInfo();
                signedInfo = signer.get_SignedInfo();
                byteTmp = signer.get_SignatureValue();
                sTmp = System.Convert::ToBase64String(byteTmp);
                sBase64Sign = "<signature>"+sTmp+"</signature>";
                info(sBase64Sign);
            }
        }

    }
    catch (Exception::CLRError)
    {
        ex = ClrInterop::getLastException();
        if (ex != null)
        {
           ex = ex.get_InnerException();
           if (ex != null)
           {
               error(ex.ToString());
           }
        }
    }

    return bSuccess;
}
```

But the result differs than I got on java. I opened a p12 key. I signed an XML sting and got the signature for this XML, but got the wrong string. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best way to sign an XML on .NET is by using a Bouncy Castle library. I hope anybody in one day will solve it on .NET framework, without using an external library, but the solution has found via using [BounsyCastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/).
This code on C# used BouncyCastle.

```
string item = string.Empty;

Pkcs12Store p12 = new Pkcs12Store();
p12.Load(_p12, _p12_psw.ToCharArray());

string alias = "";
foreach (string al in p12.Aliases)
{
    if (p12.IsKeyEntry(al) && p12.GetKey(al).Key.IsPrivate)
    {
        alias = al;
        break;
    }
}

//signature
var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlDoc);
ISigner signer = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA1withRSA");
signer.Init(true,p12.GetKey(alias).Key);
signer.BlockUpdate(data, 0, data.Length);

var sign = signer.GenerateSignature();

string base64Sign = Convert.ToBase64String(sign);
item = "<signature>"+base64Sign+"</signature>", base64Sign);
```

Comment: First of all, your Java code clearly doesn't use XML based signatures, so this cannot be a solution to the problem *stated in the question*. Just stating that BC works because it provides XML sig is not an answer whichever way you look at it.

Answer (score 1):

The Java code doesn't say anything about XML, so I don't know if you learned anything about porting code, but if you do use XML in C# then it's going to fail.

In short, you need to use the RSA functions directly. Starting with [`RSA.Create()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.create?view=netframework-4.8#System_Security_Cryptography_RSA_Create) might make a lot of sense in most languages. However, .NET is rather certificate / key based (you perform operations **on** the key rather than **using** the key, for better or worse, and private keys are considered part of the certificate that they belong to). So using [a constructor to read PKCS#12](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Security_Cryptography_X509Certificates_X509Certificate2__ctor_System_Byte___System_Security_SecureString_) is probably a better starting point.

That's all for this little tutorial. I don't believe for a second that you thought that your code would be a correct port, so start over. Happy programming.

---

EDIT: Oh, one last hint: SHA1withRSA is RSA using PKCS#1 v1.5 padding for signature generation, using SHA-1 as underlying hash function (which of course means it is SHATTERED and more).

Comment: The format for private key on .NET is RSA-PKCS1-KeyEx

Comment: In my case the format of private key for java is PKCS#8

Comment: No, it isn't, at least **not in the question you've provided**. Because of that the answer to your own question is also wrong. Glad you got it solved, but this isn't going to help anybody else, so I have to downvote because of that.